# Should form tags be used in React if I am just calling a function on submit?

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating an application that contains a list of search results (SearchResultsComponent) and a dropdown filter (FiltersComponent). The SearchResultsComponent filters the list of its search results based on what filters are selected in the FiltersComponent. SearchResultsComponent keeps the state of which filter is selected. It does this by passing a function to FiltersComponent (setFilters()) so that a filter can be selected in FiltersComponent, and then have the filter saved in the SearchResultsComponent state.

My question is whether it makes sense to wrap the filter selection part of the FiltersComponent in a form tag since it's not really submitting anything, but rather just selecting a state and calling a function passed to it from its parent. The alternative would be to ditch the form tags and instead have the callback called by the apply filters button.

This is what it looks like with the form tag

```
class FiltersComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  setFilters(filters) {
    this.props.setFilters(filters)
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <form onSubmit={this.setFilters(this.state.filters)}>
        ...inputs that let you select a filter from a list of filters...
        <input type="submit" value="Set Filters" />
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

This is what it the alternative would look like

```
class FiltersComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  setFilters(filters) {
    this.props.setFilters(filters)
  }

  render() {
    return(
      ...inputs that let you select a filter from a list of filters...
      <input type="submit" value="Set Filters" onClick={this.setFilters(this.state.filters)} />
    )
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you need to handle enter automatically - you should use <form>. If not - whatever you like. Consider using redux-form.

Comment: That's a good point I didn't think of that. Also we're only using React at the moment, but redux-form might be a good tool for us to look into in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML tags should be used for their semantic meaning, not for any built-in functionality. ie: You should use a form tag only if some area of your site is a form. As HTML has evolved, it has emphasized the semantics of the page more and more, as can be noted by the introduction of purely-semantic tags such as `<main>`, `<header>`, and `<footer>`.

Based on that, you can decide which tags to use simply: Only use a `form` tag if something actually *is* a form. Don't use `form` tags just for the submitting functionality. The tags on your page are important for code that processes webpages such as Google Web Light.

In your case, you should use the callback version.