# Post request with Bcrypt not recognized in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, bcrypt, prisma

I am building a simple login function with nextJS, so far I was able to store new username and encrypted password from register page. Login function would be similar except I need to compare password in db and input. I use `postgres`, `prisma` for my backend.

### Problem

But when I tried to compare password of input and db for login, for some reason the request method doesn't get processed, although I get no error in terminal. Why my post request: comparing the 2  passwords, is not working?

I think something is missing when I make a request?

### code

#### `login.tsx`

```js
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import { useState } from 'react'
const Login: NextPage = () => {
    const [email, getEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, getPassword] = useState('')

    const signIn = async () => {
        console.log("Sign in function")
        try {
            if (true) {
                const body = {
                    email,
                    password,
                }

                await fetch('/api/login/', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    body: JSON.stringify(body),
                })
                console.log('requested')
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }

    return (
        <>

            <form className="space-y-6" action="#" method="POST">
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="email" >
                        Email address
                    </label>
                    <div className="mt-1">
                        <input
                            id="email"
                            name="email"
                            type="email"
                            autoComplete="email"
                            required
                            onChange={(e) => { getEmail(e.target.value) }}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="password" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                        Password
                    </label>
                    <div className="mt-1">
                        <input
                            id="password"
                            name="password"
                            type="password"
                            autoComplete="current-password"
                            required
                            onChange={(e) => { getPassword(e.target.value) }}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button
                    onClick={() => { signIn }}
                >
                    Sign in
                </button>
        </form>

        </>
    )
}


export default Login
```

#### `/api/login/` ( `/api/login.tsx` )

```js
import { compare } from 'bcrypt';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import prisma from './api.prisma';

export default async function apilog (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {

    const { 
        email,
        password,
      } = req.body

    console.log("From body", email, password)
    
    const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where:{
            email: email
        }
    })

    const hash: any = user?.password

    compare(password, hash, (err, same)=>{
        if(same){
            console.log("Logged in!")
        }
        else{
            console.log("Not logged in!")
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: Make sure both files are placed correctly inside `pages` folder. `login.tsx` should be inside `pages` and the API handler should be in `/pages/api/login/index.ts`

Answer (score 0):

When I removed `<form>` tag, it worked.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43327521/should-form-tags-be-used-in-react-if-i-am-just-calling-a-function-on-submit#:%7E:text=Don%27t%20use%20form%20tags,should%20use%20the%20callback%20version.) for more